# How to Fetch the Selected Checkbox ID and Corresponding Text box Value in Ionic3 Framework

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I have made the following tries and I am able to fetch the Selected Checkbox Value but Unable to Fetch the Textbox Value that has been Entered. So i am in need of some suggestions.

**HTML File**

```
<ion-row class="service" *ngFor="let singleBarberService of allBarberServices">
 <ion-col col-7 padding>
      <ion-checkbox value="{{singleBarberService.service_id}}" (click)="clickSelectBox(singleBarberService)"></ion-checkbox> &nbsp;{{singleBarberService.service_name}} <br>
 </ion-col>
 <ion-col col-5>
      <ion-input type="number" placeholder="Amount" min="0" step="0.01" name="amountservice" #amountservice required></ion-input>  
 </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Note: `allBarberServices` Contains the JSON Array and it Displays the APP Page has the below screenshot.

[image]

**TS File:**

```
clickSelectBox(itemKey){
     const foundAt = this.selectedQuestions.indexOf(itemKey);
     if (foundAt >= 0) {
        this.selectedQuestions.splice(foundAt, 1);
     } else {
        this.selectedQuestions.push(itemKey);
    }
    console.log('Item Key: '+ itemKey.service_id);
    console.log(this.amountservice.value); // fetch only the First Textbox Value
    console.log(this.selectedQuestions); // This Displays all the Selected Checkbox Items 
  }
```

Comment: you haven't done any binding to your input: Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987674/ionic-2-get-ion-input-value) on how to bind your input value.

Comment: I have to use [(ngModel)] as per the Link that you have suggested right. Is there any way that i can add the service ID to the Text box Model Name...